# Is it possible to make the Ctrl-Tab source file switching window (IDE Navigator) in Visual Studio have wider columns?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Some of my source files have long file names and when I press Ctrl-Tab or Shift-Ctrl-Tab, the filenames that are displayed in the Active Files column of the IDE Navigator get truncated (and replaced by an ellipsis) after the 23rd-24th character and become indistinguishable. I am wondering if there is a config file or registry setting somewhere for making the columns in the IDE Navigator wider so that larger file names can fit in the columnar display.

I wouldn't mind making the entire Navigator window larger as well, if it has a max width. When it pops up, I am not interested in seeing the code underneath it, just the filenames of the files that I am about to switch to through consecutive presses of (Shift-)-Ctrl-Tab. I know there is a secret registry entry for showing thumbnails in the Navigator, but I am wondering if there is some control over column width as well.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @HansPassant, [Some info about IDE Navigator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/17/using-the-ide-navigator-vstiptool0023.aspx).

Comment: @HandPassant, [IDE Navigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a96fx0b9(v=vs.100).aspx) is the MS official name for the Ctrl-Tab window switcher in Visual Studio since VS 2005.

Comment: This is the closest thing I found that might help you identify your files a little faster https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/11/17/thumbnail-previews-in-the-ide-navigator/. It doesn't seem to work in VS 2017 though.